# How do I set up Laravel Nova to run on a subdomain?

Tags: laravel, nginx, subdomain, laravel-nova

I am setting up Laravel Nova 4 to run on `portal.example.com` instead of `example.com/admin`. Logging in works fine, but when I try to add an item in Nova, the request responds with an error:

Request URL: https://portal.example.com/nova-api/users?editing=true&editMode=create
Status Code: `422`
Response: `{"message":"validation.min.string","errors":{"password":["validation.min.string"]}}`

When I try to edit an item, a similar error occurs:

Request URL: `https://portal.example.com/nova-api/companies/2?viaResource=&viaResourceId=&viaRelationship=&editing=true&editMode=update`
Status Code: `422`
Response: `{"message":"validation.required","errors":{"package":["validation.required"]}}`

When I try to delete an item, a different error occurs:

Request URL: `https://portal.example.com/nova-api/companies?search=&filters=W10%3D&trashed=&resources[]=2`
Status Code: `500`
Error in laravel.log: `[2022-08-03 08:17:21] production.ERROR: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, null given {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, null given at /home/forge/example.com/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Http/Requests/DeleteResourceRequest.php:48)`

The error message led me to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/2886), in which the thread starter determines that "the problem was Nginx misconfiguration. The query string was not passed down to Laravel". This is my Nginx config:

```
include forge-conf/example.com/before/*;

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_tokens off;
    server_name portal.example.com;
    root /home/forge/example.com/public;

    # forge SSL stuff removed

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/example.com/server/*;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/example.com/after/*;
```

Please note that there is another Nginx config for my main Laravel app.

This is Laravel's .env file:

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_KEY=base64:abcd
APP_URL=https://example.com.com

NOVA_APP_NAME=example
NOVA_DOMAIN_NAME=portal.example.com
NOVA_LICENSE_KEY=abcd

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=example
DB_USERNAME=forge
DB_PASSWORD="abcd"

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=memcached

REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mandrillapp.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=example
MAIL_PASSWORD=abcd
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="info@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

SCOUT_DRIVER=meilisearch
SCOUT_QUEUE=true
MEILISEARCH_HOST=http://127.0.0.1:7700
MEILISEARCH_KEY=abcd

SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=example.com
SPA_URL=https://example.com
SESSION_DOMAIN=portal.example.com
```

Please help me find out what I am missing. For me it looks like all query strings are passed down to Nova, but considering that I don't really understand Nginx I think it's likely that the problem is to be found there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run nova on a subdomain by updating `config/nova.php` file like the following:

```
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Nova Domain Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value is the "domain name" associated with your application. This
    | can be used to prevent Nova's internal routes from being registered
    | on subdomains which do not need access to your admin application.
    |
    */

    'domain' => env('NOVA_DOMAIN_NAME', null),
```

You can replace the domain value here or define an env variable which it's value is your subdomain.

On the other hand, you need to configure Apache/Nginx to handle the new subdomain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName admin.mysite.localhost
    ServerAlias admin.mysite.localhost
    ServerAdmin admin@mysite.localhost

    ...
    
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    
    #   Per-Server Logging:
    CustomLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/ssl_request.log" \
    "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
    
</VirtualHost>
```

I hope this would help.